# Syntax to copy a file in Laravel (5.4) from local to AWS S3?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, amazon-s3, laravel-5.4

What's the best way to copy an uploaded file from my Laravel installation (running on Heroku) to S3? I can't do a direct to S3 upload, as it's an image that I'm locally generating a thumbnail for. I also don't want to use any extra libraries etc. (sledgehammer to crack a nut etc.). File needs to go in a particular folder in my S3 bucket. Is this the only/best way? :-

```
Storage::disk('s3')->put('S3_folder_name/file.jpg', file_get_contents('my_local_file.jpg'));
```

Thanks

Comment: What is wrong with the method you've provided?

Comment: The method you provided is how I would do it. It’s actually similar to how I do it in a production system where my client edits their own inventory images.